# assembly programs x32 work under windows x64

Tags: assembly, tasm

I've started learning Assembly recently to be able to work programs that run under Windows, I had learned some Assembly several years ago (back then I used TASM), but with the new CPU I decided to start using NASM.

My question is: can a program made using TASM still be run under 64bit machines? my general understanding is that 64bit OSs can run a program made for 32bit OSs, but not vice versa, a 32bit OS can't run a program made ti be run under a 64bit OS, does the same apply in this case?

in other words, can I still use TASM to make programs that run under 32bit and 64 bit OSs? or do I have to migrate to NASM?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [x86 assembly on x64 operating systems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125936/x86-assembly-on-x64-operating-systems)

Comment: Yes, the header of a .exe file includes information that indicates if the program is a 32 or 64 bit program.